# Fill editText Value from button click on another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts and my UI will look Menu Bar

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|                                                     |
|                                       Button 1      |      
-----------------------------------------------------
|                       |                               |        
|      S1               |               S2              | 
-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       |
|                   EditText                            |    
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The XML For my upper part

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|                                                     |
|                                       Button 1      |      
-----------------------------------------------------
|                       |                               |        
|      S1               |               S2              | 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ag.ap.tagassigner.TagAssignmentHolder">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The Text field is in an fragment and it is in another layout

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       |
|                   EditText                            |    
--------------------------------------------------------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ag.ap.tagassigner.TagAssignment">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/serialNoField"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:hint= "@string/serialno_plh"
        />
```

I am having the button in the menu bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/android">

    <!-- Refresh -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/action_barcode"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:onClick="scanBarcode"
        />

    <!-- Help -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/action_camera"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />


</menu>
```

I want fill the value of editText if click on Button 1 . How do i acheive it ?

Comment: Use Intent to pass data from one layout to another. [See intent passing data Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7325248/6448399)

Comment: But in my case the intent will be already loaded .

Comment: I can't see `button` in your xml. where is that button coming from ?

Comment: @NiteshVerma : I have update the question. The button is available as an menu bar

Comment: Use an interface to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. For that try to change your activity to fragment and put in frame and after that use this frame in your activity and that will change your editText Value from button click. For button click of other fragment try to use buttoName.performClick(). Hope this one help you.